# Не правильно считает высоту дочерних отображений ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-view

Я использую несколько ListView для отображения двух списков в одном окне, знаю что решение не особо но в моем случае оно оказалось более быстрым. Я присваиваю высоту ListView считая высоту всех ее дочерних элементов, элементы это обычные TextView и считается она в целом правильно за исключением тех случаев когда TextView разбивается на несколько строк, тогда высота устанавливается меньше чем есть на самом деле.
Вот код который подсчитывает высоту дочерних элементов:

```html
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Как можно правильно подсчитать высоту всех дочерних элементов в списке?

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант, если оно не учитывает количество строк, то вы можете попробовать считать сколько строк в `TextView`  - `textView.getLinesCount();`
и ложить значение по тегу для каждого `View`.

После чего вы кода вызываете строку

```
view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
```

достаете оттуда значение  `view.getTag();`   и в зависимости от количества строк, добавляете нужное значение к общей высоте `ListView`.

Это скорее костыль нежели решение, но вдруг поможет!